# AndEngine error in TexturePackParser just after getting it from github

Tags: android, constructor, bitmap, textures, andengine

I'm encountering a problem with the AndEngine : I just downloaded it from the github repos [here](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich) and after this, I have an error in the project AndEngineTexturePackerExtension, in the java file TexturePackParses.java. At line 156, eclipse tells me

"he constructor BitmapTexture(TextureManager, BitmapTexture.BitmapTextureFormat, TextureOptions) is undefined".

Here is the concerned code :

```
> try {
>       return new BitmapTexture(this.mTextureManager, BitmapTextureFormat.fromPixelFormat(pixelFormat), textureOptions) {
>       @Override
>       protected InputStream onGetInputStream() throws IOException {
>               return TexturePackParser.this.onGetInputStream(file);
>       }
>       };          }
```

I don't understand because I have not changed anything in the code. I tried early on my laptop to add an argument to the constructor but I couldn't launch any app....

Does somebody have a solution ?

Thx !

Sébastien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been reported here  https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineTexturePackerExtension/issues/2

There is a workaround listed there as well.